# The process going on in BIOS and UEFI when they want to choose bootloader in dual boot systems

Tags: linux, boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios

I learned something about bootloader, UEFI and BIOS but now i have question about them.

at first I want to know how BIOS can decide which bootloader should load in dual boot systems

In UEFI i know we have EFI partition that contains bootloader, kernel image, device driver and ...
in dual boot system(like windows & ubuntu) both bootloaders store in one EFI partition so how does UEFI find should load the grub at first ?

Comment: not a nix specific question

Comment: BIOS will make a list of disks and order it so that whichever disk is selected as the current boot disk will be the first on that list. Then it will read block #0 from that disk, and if it contains the correct value in the last two bytes, BIOS will execute the contents of the block as 16-bit real-mode program code. Whatever happens after that is decided by that bit of code and whatever it loads next. On dual-boot Linux systems, block #0 will usually contain the first small part of GRUB.

Comment: UEFI has some non-volatile memory (NVRAM, the equivalent of CMOS memory for BIOS) which can contain *UEFI variables*. Those can be used to define a triplet of 1.) partition GUID, 2.) bootloader filename, 3.) a human-readable name for the bootloader/OS, for each permanently-installed OS. UEFI will use these variables to find the bootloader(s) it will attempt to load. In Linux, you can use the `efibootmgr -v` command as root to view them, and with other options to modify them if needed. In Windows, `bcdedit` can do the same job, but it's not exactly user-friendly.